# Converting a dataframe to a tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tensorflow, tfrecord

I have a pandas dataframe that contains 1 column and 60 million rows. Rows are either filled with sentences or are empty. How can I convert it to a tensorflow dataset, save it and later load it to another program?

This is what I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from pandas_tfrecords import pd2tf, tf2pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
pd2tf(df, './tfrecords')
pd2tf.pandas_to_tfrecords(df, 'folder', compression_type=None, compression_level=None, columns=None, max_mb=None)
```

It seems that the code is run without any problem but the dataset is not saved to the given directory.
How can I build my tensorflow dataset, save it, and read it into another program?

Comment: try `"folder/mydata.tfrecord"`

Comment: Use `tf.io.TFRecordWriter('data.tfrecord')`. Have a look at [Tensorflow Tfrecord](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord) guide. Thanks!